# Swift Strong Delegate Reference

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code to allow for updating the image of a model.

```
extension MyModel {
    public func updateImage(completionHandler: () -> Void) {
        let imagePickerController: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        let delegate = UpdateImageHandler(completionHandler: completionHandler)
        imagePickerController.delegate = delegate

        UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(imagePickerController, animated: true)
    }
}

class UpdateImageHandler: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    let completionHandler: () -> Void

    init(completionHandler: () -> Void) {
        self.completionHandler = completionHandler
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        print("HERE")

        guard
            let image: UIImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage,
            let data = image.pngData()
        else {
            completionHandler()
            return
        }

        print("HERE 1")

        APIManager.uploadImage(data: data) {
            completionHandler()
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `imagePickerController` method is never called. I expect it to print `HERE` and `HERE 1`. But currently it doesn't print anything.

I believe this is because `delegate` is getting deallocated from memory before that method gets called.

How can I fix this so `delegate` doesn't get deallocated until `imagePickerController` is done (`APIManager.uploadImage` competitionHandler has been called)?

Normally I could probably attach the `UpdateImageHandler` to the instance that will hold it or something. Problem is this code is in an extension. And `MyModel` is a protocol.

Of course it's all much more complicated than this, but this I believe represents the least amount of code needed to understand the problem.

Comment: add a `var updateImageHandler:UpdateImageHandler?` to the `MyModel` protocol; You need a property to hold a strong reference to the delegate.  I suspect that this function does't belong on the `MyModel` protocol; It should be part of a protocol that is implemented by a concrete class.

Comment: Hence the second part of my comment.  I suspect their design is just wrong

Comment: @Paulw11, yeah seems like

Answer (score 0):

You should re-write the protocol like so:

```
protocol MyModel
{
    var updateImageHandler: UpdateImageHandler { get set }

    func updateImage(completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
}
```

Then your function in the extension would look like:

```
extension MyModel
{
    public mutating func updateImage(completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
    {
        let imagePickerController: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

        self.updateImageHandler = UpdateImageHandler(completionHandler: completionHandler)
        imagePickerController.delegate = updateImageHandler

        UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(imagePickerController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

This ensures that the `updateImageHandler` is not deallocated.

Comment: This would kinda violate SRP, model should not need to know/care about UI stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I want to say that your `updateImage` function should not be part of your protocol, simply because UI stuff should not burden the data layer.

Secondly, the problem you're facing is caused by the fact that `UpdateImageHandler` gets deallocated as soon as all strong references to it are gone. And in your code there's only one strong reference - the `delegate` local variable from `updateImage`, and once the function returns, that strong reference gets destroyed, taking the `UpdateImageHandler` with it.

To come back to the first paragraph, functions like this should live at the UI level, since they involve ViewController operations. For example if you'd do this operation within another view controller, then you could save a strong reference in that view controller, e.g. via a dedicated property in the controller.

However, if you're keen to the current implementation (design), or you can't refactoring right now, you can use a self-referencing solution. Note that I would strongly recommend this be a temporary solution until the design problems in your app are resolved.

So, in regards to the above, what you need is for `UpdateImageHandler` to hold a reference to itself:

```
class UpdateImageHandler {
    private(set) var selfRef: UpdateImageHandler?

    init(completionHandler: () -> Void) {
        self.completionHandler = completionHandler
        selfRef = self
    }
```

Note that I omitted some parts of your code to not add noise to the solution.

The above will make sure the `UpdateImageHandler` instance won't get deallocated before having a chance to do its job. Unfortunately, the above code created a retain cycle which means that the instance will never be deallocated. We need to fix this too, we need to break the retain cycle somewhere, and this can be done in the image picker delegate methods:

```swift
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    // do your job
    selfRef = nil // this breaks the cycle, allowing deallocation
}
```

But that's not enough, what if the user cancelled the image picker? You'd need to also address this situation, break the cycle in that case too:

```swift
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    selfRef = nil
}
```

It's important to do this on all possible scenarios, to avoid situation where retain cycles are still existing, leading to memory leaks.